# How can I set up a letsencrypt SSL certificate and use it in a Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, spring, ssl, spring-boot, lets-encrypt

I'm new to securing a server so I don't really know much about this but I need to get my Spring Boot Application that is running on a Digital Ocean Droplet to use HTTPS.

My idea is to register a letsencrypt certificate and then tell Spring to use that.

However, I have no idea how to do that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 144):

I wrote 2 blog posts about Let's Encrypt and **Spring Boot**.

1. **Issuing a certificate.** [Spring Boot Application Secured by Let’s Encrypt Certificate](http://www.heydari.be/2016/05/14/Spring-Boot-Application-Secured-by-Lets-Encrypt-Certificate.html)
2. **Renewing a certificate**. [Let’s Encrypt Certificate Renewal: for Spring Boot](http://www.heydari.be/2016/08/10/Lets-Encrypt-Certificate-Renewal-for-Spring-Boot.html)

In a nutshell, steps are as follows:

1. Pulling the [Let's Encrypt client](https://github.com/certbot/certbot) (certbot).
2. Generating a certificate for your domain (e.g. example.com)

   `./certbot-auto certonly -a standalone -d example.com -d www.example.com`

Things are generated in `/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com`. Spring Boot expects PKCS#12 formatted file. It means that you must convert the keys to a PKCS#12 keystore (e.g. using OpenSSL). As follows:

3. Open
   `/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com` directory.
4. ```
   `openssl pkcs12 -export -in fullchain.pem -inkey privkey.pem -out keystore.p12 -name tomcat -CAfile chain.pem -caname root`
   ```

The file *keystore.p12* with PKCS12 is now generated in      `/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com`.

It's time to configure your Spring Boot application. Open the application.properties file and put following properties there:

```
server.port=8443
security.require-ssl=true
server.ssl.key-store=/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=<your-password>
server.ssl.keyStoreType=PKCS12
server.ssl.keyAlias=tomcat
```

Read my [blog post](http://www.heydari.be/2016/05/14/Spring-Boot-Application-Secured-by-Lets-Encrypt-Certificate.html) for further details and remarks.

Comment: Awesome. 

I think this is pretty much how I finally got it going, but I had to pull from 2 or 3 different sources and bumble my way through it. This will make it much easier when I have to renew.

Comment: Do I have to use server.port: 8443 in production to? Or server.port: 80 is fine?

Comment: Where can I find/define key-store-password?

Comment: When you're performing the steps, you'll be asked to choose a password. Then you use that password for key-store-password.

Comment: My application said "PKCS12 not found". So I created a `JKS` from the `PKCS12` and changed the keyStoreType to `JKS`. `keytool -importkeystore -destkeystore keys.jks -deststoretype pkcs12 -srckeystore keys.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12` from https://pubs.vmware.com/view-50/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.view.installation.doc%2FGUID-06A2FF09-777C-44F0-B240-497E771379F3.html

Comment: @EmadVanBen then every time let's encrypt renew the cert, I have to recreate the p12 manually?

Comment: save me alot of time. tks.     but i recommand to remove the `-a standalone` in step 2, 
   and put key-store in classpath instead of original folder, like this:
`server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore.p12`
for who don't know that the classpath is the `src/main/resources` folder in the spring server

Comment: FYI, even if your password key not provided, it throws error you should add key-store-password even fi pass is empty

Comment: I'm using windows cmd and git bash command line, how would I execute the command in step 2?

Comment: @EmadVanBen - Can you please update the links in the answer? None of them are working.

Comment: @Nikhil, it's fixed now.

Comment: @EmadVanBen - Thanks!

Comment: install.rst -> -cerbot/cerbot/docs -> We used to have a shell script named ``certbot-auto`` to help people install
Certbot on UNIX operating systems, however, this script is no longer supported.
If you want to uninstall ``certbot-auto``, you can follow our instructions
:doc:`here <uninstall>`.

Comment: The guide needs to be updated as it is no longer valid. I hope the author wishes to update his splendid work.

Comment: @FedericoGalimberti, thanks. I am willing to update my blog. Could you please let me know which instruction?

Comment: Unfortunately certbot-auto no longer exists. I have tested your page with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. I can't get a certificate.

Answer (score 9):

**Step 1: Download certbot from git**

You need to fetch the source code of Let's Encrypt on your server which your domain address is pointing to. This step may take a couple minutes.

> $ git clone https://github.com/certbot/certbot
>
> $ cd certbot
>
> $ ./certbot-auto --help

Remark: Python 2.7.8 (or above) should be installed beforehand.

**Step2: generates certificates and a private key**

By executing following command in your terminal, Let's Encrypt generates certificates and a private key for you.

> $ ./certbot-auto certonly -a standalone \
>
> ```
> -d example.com -d example.com
> ```

Remark:Keys are generated in /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com directory

**Step3: Generate PKCS12 Files From PEM Files**

To convert the PEM files to PKCS12 version:
Go to /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com
convert the keys to PKCS12 using OpenSSL in the terminal as follows.

> $ openssl pkcs12 -export -in fullchain.pem \
>
> ```
>        -inkey privkey.pem \
>
>            -out keystore.p12 \
>
>        -name tomcat \
>
>        -CAfile chain.pem \
>
>        -caname root
> ```

Enter Export Password:

Verifying - Enter Export Password:

(Note:- Write single line at a time and press enter)

**Step4: Configuration of Spring Boot Application**

Open your *'application.properties'*
Put this configuration there.

> server.port=8443 security.require-ssl=true
>
> server.ssl.key-store=/etc/letsencrypt/live/*example.com*/keystore.p12
>
> server.ssl.key-store-password= *password*
>
> server.ssl.keyStoreType= PKCS12
>
> server.ssl.keyAlias= tomcat

Comment: well explained =)

Comment: -bash: ./certbot-auto: No such file or directory  I am getting this exception

Comment: @Kumaresan, I guess they have updated the git, I will add new steps to pull this, Thank you

Comment: ok sure. I will pull it. thanks

Answer (score 7):

Another option is to use Spring Boot Starter ACME:

https://github.com/creactiviti/spring-boot-starter-acme

ACME (Automatic Certificate Management Environment) it the protocol used by LetsEncrypt to automatically issue certs.

Comment: This was good advice, but it is deprecated now (It does not support LetsEncrypts ACME API v2). Check https://letsencrypt.org/docs/client-options/ for other clients that are up to date!

Answer (score 2):

For spring boot webflux the configuration of properties changed

```
server.port=443

server.ssl.enabled=true//the changed line
server.ssl.keyAlias=netty
server.ssl.key-store=path
server.ssl.key-store-password=password
server.ssl.keyStoreType=PKCS12
```

Comment: The default value for `server.ssl.enabled` is true, so this technically isn't needed.

Answer (score 1):

[letsencrypt-tomcat](https://github.com/schnatterer/letsencrypt-tomcat) queries **and** refreshes certs via Let's encrypt **at runtime** (no restarts needed).
It works with standalone and embedded Tomcat as well as Spring Boot.

It's packaged into a Docker image, allowing for easy reuse. The image contains:

- [dehydrated](http://dehydrated.io/)  to manage certs via Let’s Encrypt,
- [tomcat-reloading-connector](https://github.com/schnatterer/tomcat-reloading-connector) for hot reloading certs at runtime after renewal,
- an init system ([dumb-init](https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init)) for properly handling tomcat and dehydrated processes,
- an entrypoint script that starts up tomcat and dehydrated as well as
- a pre-compiled version of Apache Portable Runtime (APR) and JNI wrappers for APR used by Tomcat (libtcnative), so tomcat delivers the best TLS performance possible.

Read this [blog post](http://blog.schnatterer.info/2020/09/21/automatic-lets-encrypt-certificates-with-apache-tomcat) to learn how to use it with your application and more about the technical details.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a small library in pure Java that allows embedded Tomcat in Spring-Boot to obtain and keep Lets Encrypt certificate fresh automatically: [Spring-Boot LetsEncrypt helper](https://github.com/valb3r/letsencrypt-helper)

It is just [one Java file](https://github.com/valb3r/letsencrypt-helper/blob/master/tomcat/src/main/java/com/github/valb3r/letsencrypthelper/tomcat/TomcatWellKnownLetsEncryptChallengeEndpointConfig.java) + dependencies on ACME4J/BouncyCastle, so that one can re-use it as a code

In short, it does the following:

1. On application start it creates KeyStore as defined in your `server.ssl` properties if it does not exist yet (and adds self-signed expired cert there).
2. Registers Tomcat connector on port 80 for HTTP-01 ACME challenge from LetsEncrypt
3. Launches thread that checks if the certificate in KeyStore is outdated or missing
4. If the certificate is outdated/missing it issues an order to LetsEncrypt and passes HTTP-01 ACME challenge on port 80.
5. After passing the challenge it stores the certificate into KeyStore defined in `server.ssl` and issues `reloadSslHostConfigs` on Tomcat HTTPS enabled connector

With these steps, the entire LetsEncrypt certificate lifecycle from the issuing to update is covered within Java application itself without any non-Java 3rd parties

Answer (score 0):

I've had some trouble when exporting .pem to .p12, keytool was not recognizing file format. Here follows the command that worked for me after many searches:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in fullchain.pem -inkey privkey.pem -out keystore.p12 -name tomcat -CAfile chain.pem -caname root -legacy -passout pass:changeit
```

After that, you'll have your file **keystore.p12**, so set the configs in application.properties like **Emad Van Ben** told before

Answer (score -1):

1. Get an SSL certificate from letsencrypt
2. Add it into a keystore using the `keytool` command in Java
3. Configure your Spring application to use the keystore generated above

The file should look like:

```
 server.port = 8443
 server.ssl.key-store = classpath:sample.jks
 server.ssl.key-store-password = secret
 server.ssl.key-password = password
```

Comment: Thanks! 
So I was kind of on the right track it looks like. 

Could anyone possibly elaborate on how i add that cert with keytool?

Comment: See the keytool help pages http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html

Comment: Maybe [this tutorials](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tags/let-s-encrypt?type=tutorials) can help.