# Issue with running Ubuntu App on Windows 10

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

Hi I have this problem why following the steps to generate SSL certificate using Letsencrypt [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36991562/how-can-i-set-up-a-letsencrypt-ssl-certificate-and-use-it-in-a-spring-boot-appli).

However when I run the command `./certbot-auto certonly -a standalone -d example.com -d www.example.com`  I got this problem:

`: not founduto: 13: ./certbot-auto: : not founduto: 15: ./certbot-auto:`

I'm sending a snippet for reference: [image: Here]

I would appreciate any help on how to fix this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the `:` is at the *start* of the line indicates you you have CR/LF line endings. You can verify this with `od -xcb certbot-auto` and checking for the `\r\n` line endings.

The error message generated would be *something* like:

```
./certbot-auto: 13: ./certbot-auto: <cr>: not found
```

with the bit after the `<cr>` overwriting the start of the message, making it look like (what you can see):

```
: not founduto: 13: ./certbot-auto:
```

So first step is the run something like `dos2unix` over your shell script and fix the line endings:

```
dos2unix certbot-auto
```

That should change the line endings and hopefully make it runnable.

Comment: Like prepending the `dos2unix` before that command? sorry, I'm a beginner.